# Proving isomorphism between rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let R be a commutative ring with unity and r ∈ R . Prove that R[x]/{x-r} =~ R using the Fundamental Theorem of Homomorphism. Hence show that R[x,y]/{y-r} =~ R[x] .
I came across this question recently. Would it be correct to write R[x]/{x-r} = R[r]?
In which case wouldn't R and R[r] be obviously isomorphic since r belongs to R.
I just started abstract algebra a few days ago, so I need to know if I am going the correct way about this and if not then what is the correct way to solve the question. Thank you.

Comment: Intuitively, that is correct. I think a rigorous proof should use the fundamental theorem of homomorphism as required in the question. Try to find a epimorphism $f:R[x]\to R$ with kernel $(x-r)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detailed hints:

Step 1: Define a homomorphism from $R[x] \to R$ whose kernel is exactly those functions $f$ whose value at $r$ is $0$.

Step 2: Show that the kernel of the above homomorphism is the polynomial multiples of $x-r$.

Step 3: Use the first isomorphism theorem to conclude the result you want.